# Can I watch YouTube videos on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, youtube

If so, how? Is there an app available, or perhaps an installable package for watching in the browser?

Comment: ⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣    html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://youtube.com/html5 and enable HTML5 playback.

Comment: sorry but enabling feather_beta is not a good idea on Ubuntu touch. Video playback will fail. (at least it does so on Galaxy Nexus 14.04- all daily builds up to today. But I believe this is generic so all devices are hit)